# Iterate over array of WinJS Promises and break if one completed successful

Tags: asynchronous, promise, winjs

I have 3 WinJS Promises that I want to call sequentially until one completes without an error.

Pseudo code:

```
var promises = [promise1,promise2,promise3];
promises.each (promise)
  promise.then (result) return result
```

Of course, I cannot use .each on the array as this would execute the promises in parallel.

So first the iteration should be sequential and if the promise returns with an error the next promise should be tried, otherwise it should return the value of the successful promise.
If no promise returns successful, then the whole loop should indicate a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want

```
return promise1.catch(function(err) {
    return promise2.catch(function(err) {
        return promise3;
    });
})
```

or (flattened)

```
makePromise1().catch(makePromise2).catch(makePromise3);
```

You can easily create this chain dynamically from an array of to-be-tried functions by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
return promiseMakers.reduce(function(p, makeNext) {
    return p.then(null, makeNext);
}, WinJS.Promise.wrapError());
```

or if you really have an array of promises (tasks that were already started to run in parallel):

```
return promises.reduce(function(p, next) {
    return p.then(null, function(err) {
        return next;
    });
}, WinJS.Promise.wrapError());
```

(which is very similar to [`Promise.any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229660.aspx), except that it waits sequentially)

Comment: Note that promises represent _already started events_ so OP is making _all three requests_ before any has had the chance to fail.

Comment: Yes, that's why I find it odd that OP has `promises = [promise1,promise2,promise3]`

Comment: yes you right, the array should not contain promises. It should contain functions that __return__ a promise. So that `next` would become `next()`?

Comment: @philk: No, you'd just use my first snippet with the `makeNext` :-) But yes, calling `next()` would be equivalent.