# Bluebird Promise.any() early reject?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm using promise library Bluebird in all my Node.js projects. For getting the content of the first existent file from a list of file paths I use `Promise.any` successfully as follows:

```
Promise.any([
   './foo/file1.yaml',
   './foo/file2.yaml',
   './foo/file3.yaml'
], function(filePath) {
    _readFile(filePath);
}),then(function(fileContent) {
    _console.log(fileContent);
});
```

My question is, how can i leave the `Promis.any` loop early if i get an error which is different from "file not found", when reading a file? The following code illustrates my question:

```
Promise.any([
   './foo/file1.yaml',
   './foo/file2.yaml',
   './foo/file3.yaml'
], function(filePath) {
    _readFile(filePath)
    .catch(function(err) {
       var res = err;
       if (err.code == FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
          // continue the Promise.any loop
       } else {
          // leave the Promise.any loop with this error
          err = new Promise.EarlyBreak(err);
       }
       Promise.reject(err);
    });
}).then(function(fileContent) {
    _console.log(fileContent);
}, function(err) {
    // the first error different from FILE_NOT_FOUND
});
```

May be `Promise.any` is not the right function?

Comment: I use bluebird in all my projects too, but haven't tried anything like this. Just an untested idea, but can you set a variable like var isErr, that you set to true if you reach that early break scenario. Then in your other promises set a repeating timer up to check the status of that var and reject if true? Wouldn't be immediate but could be a pretty quick exit.

Comment: Uh, [according to the API docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) `Promise.any` doesn't take a callback? And there's no "loop" anyway, they're awaited in parallel? I'd recommend to write it out manually using `reduce` or recursion.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `Promise.any` doesn't take a callback. I want the files to be checked sequentially, and the next only iff the prevoius does not exist. In all other cases I want to get an error. Currently, I implemented this using `Promise.each` and a global `var` but I thought, there's a better solution. I'll start again thinking about using `Promise.reduce`.

Comment: Actually, I see no way to stop `reduce` from calling the accumulator if i have successfully read a file.

Comment: Here's two more patterns that would do it. See Jake Archibald's comments: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/359#issuecomment-49329009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving a `Promise.any()` loop early is conceptually problematic in that `Promise.any()` is an aggregator not a loop, and accepts an array of promises, each of which has a life of its own, not determined by `Promise.any()`.

However, starting with an array of paths, the loop you seek can be expressed as a `paths.reduce(...)` expression, which builds a `.catch()` chain, straightforwardly as follows :

```
function getFirstGoodFileContent(paths) {
    paths.reduce(function(promise, path) {
        return promise.catch(function() {
            return _readFile(path);
        });
    }, Promise.reject()); // seed the chain with a rejected promise.
}
```

*[Catch chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424304/1048572): credit [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)*

The .catch chain thus built, will progress to the next iteration on failure, or skip to the end of the chain on success. This flow control is the inverse of what happens in a more normal .then chain (seeded with a fulfilled promise).

But that's not quite everything. An extra condition is required - namely to "leave the [Promise.any] loop early if I get an error which is different from 'file not found'". This is very simply engineered into the catch chain by sending all errors except FILE_NOT_FOUND down the success path, thereby :

- effecting the required flow control (skipping the rest of the chain), but
- ending up with an error condition going down the success route - undesirable but recoverable.

```
function getFirstGoodFileContent(paths) {
    paths.reduce(function(promise, path) {
        return promise.catch(function() {
            return _readFile(path).catch(function(err) {
                if (err.code == FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
                    throw err; // Rethrow the error to continue down the catch chain, seeking a good path.
                } else {
                    return { isError: true, message: err.code }; // Skip the rest of the catch chain by returning a "surrogate success object".
                }
            });
        });
    }, Promise.reject()).then(function(fileContent) {
        // You will arrive here either because :
        // * a good path was found, or
        // * a non-FILE_NOT_FOUND error was encountered.
        // The error condition is detectable by testing `fileContent.isError`
        if (fileContent.isError) {
            throw new Error(fileContent.message); // convert surrogate success to failure.
        } else {
            return fileContent; // Yay, genuine success.
        }
    });
}
```

So you can now call :

```
getFirstGoodFileContent([
    './foo/file1.yaml',
    './foo/file2.yaml',
    './foo/file3.yaml'
]).then(function(fileContent) {
    _console.log(fileContent);
}, function(error) {
    // error will be due to :
    // * a non-FILE_NOT_FOUND error having occurred, or
    // * the final path having resulted in an error.
    console.log(error); 
});
```

Comment: You credit me in your answer - thanks! - but do you refer to my comment above or another answer of mine?

Comment: @Bergi, another answer - a comment I think - a good year ago. You put me right on the simplicity of a catch chain in lieu of some convoluted promise inversion pattern I had devised. I can't find it - possibly deleted?

Comment: A [quick search in my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+reduce+catch) brought up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27424304/1048572) which seems to be a likely candidate :-)

Comment: @Bergi, that's as good as any, though not the one I remember.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have to handle an actual error the same as a successful file content retrieval. Nice! Further, files are read only if the previous read failed. After a successful file reading the remaining paths don't create a promise. So it's a very lightweight looping over the remainig paths. Thanks!